# What is the part name/type for my fridge door sensor connector?

Tags: electrical, refrigerator

I have a three-door LG fridge. Each door has a button that gets pushed in when the door is closed, so it can turn off the light, etc. The button is connected to the wiring with a U-shaped plug connector.

Can anyone tell me what this connector is called and/or where I can get some?

Pics are attached.

EDIT: FWIW, the connector it hooks up to is an LG AP4441529, viewable at http://www.appliancepartspros.com/lg-switch-push-6600jb3007e-ap4441529.html I just need the connectors themselves.

Thanks in advance.

[image][image][image]

Comment: Can you describe why you need these connectors? The connectors may very well be customized parts made for LG and could be next to impossible to obtain on the open market unless LG offers them as a spare through their distribution network. If your needs are understood it may be possible to recommend a different solution.

Comment: I was hoping to insert an on-off switch. I want to be able to temporarily suspend the pushbuttons so that they don't cause the light to go on when I open the door. I could always splice into the wires, but that would be messy (not to mention warranty issues). If I can insert a male and female, I can wire a switch between them and then control the pushbuttons.

Comment: For now, I opened it up and disconnected one of them, but then will have to open the cover and wire it back, and, etc.

Comment: On modern refrigerators the door switch wiring likely routes to a microprocessor control board and then the control board separately controls the light on a different circuit. It is possible that the microprocessor may use the door switch signalling for other things than just the light! In such situation your scheme to override the door switch could be a bad idea. Why not instead simply remove the light bulbs from inside the refrigerator and attach a magnetic flash light on the door for those instances when you need a light to look inside.

Comment: Or instead install your cutout switch into the light circuit instead.

Comment: Actually, it does, and I know it does. Lots of fridges have a "Sabbath" mode to turn it off for religious reasons; and in some places, installers will put in a little clip to hold it down, so it is as if the door were closed. This is very useful, but my fridge doesn't come with it. Ironically, the model released the following year has it, but mine doesn't. I have those clips, they are a pain in the rear. Wanted to put in a switch. Do you know of any way I can track down what that connector is even called?

Comment: There is unlikely to be any "special" name for the connector beyond "door switch connector". The connector itself appears to be a customized nylon block. The terminals are crimped to the wires and then pushed into place from the back side of the connector body. You could try looking at the switch itself, identify the part number and manufacturer and then contact them to see if they offer the connector as an accessory for their switch. --- I would look first at the idea to override at the light.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelKaras, I have the part for the switch itself. Was so hopeful.

Comment: What is the model number of your fridge?

Comment: The actual model number is GRF258, although the plug itself is identical to that on the LFX259 series (and several others).

Comment: The shell will only be available from the manufacturer as a custom item. The blade sockets inserted in the shell are "Quick Connect/Quick Disconnect" type and searching on Digikey will allow you to buy a packet of 100 pretty easily. You need to measure the blade width on the device that it plugs to. And also need a crimper that will properly attach the socket to the wire. That's often the hardest part.

Comment: Is that it? It is just a custom plastic shell around a pair of quick disconnect connectors? If that is it, I should be able to get two females to plug into the male end, two males to fit into the plastic casing above, and just wire them up, shouldn't it?

Comment: "crimper to attach the socket to the wire". I assume you mean the quick disconnect plug to any ole wire?

Comment: create a widget that keeps the button depressed when the door is opened.

Comment: @mike I would love to, but there are multiple connectors - French door fridge - and the shape is weird.

Comment: @deitch - post a photo and i'll invent one for you.